# How can I make an element as wide as it is high in css?

Tags: css

I know I can make an element as high as it is wide using padding-top/bottom

```
#element {
  width: 40%;
  padding-top: 40%;
}
```

The reason the above works is because, when giving padding-top/bottom a percentage value, it is relative to the **width** of the parent, not the height.

how can i do the same thing, just making it as wide as it is high instead of the other way around?

It needs to be responsive, and the solution should work in all major browser including IE8+

Comment: Is setting the width and height explicitly out of the question?

Comment: Verymuch so. I need to have at least 15 characters so thats why I’m writing this sentence.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to go with JS.

Comment: wow, am i tired or what ? i cannot understand problems submitted ! what are you trying to do ? it is not clear for me !

Comment: The same way {width: XX%; padding-top: XX%;} will make an element as high as you, I mean,,, as high as it is wide :). I need a solution to how I can do the same, just the other way around. Having it at all times as wide as it is hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need javascript
using jquery it should be something like:

```
$('#element').css({
     width: + $('#element').height()
})
```

but the above is very rough I didn't even test it

**Update it works- see my fiddle:**
[fiddle for above](http://jsfiddle.net/HxysS/)

or I think I might been a bit sloppy if you prefer:

```
var el=$('#element');
el.css({
    width: + el.height()
});
```

[this](http://jsfiddle.net/HxysS/1/)

Comment: Thank you, but I need it to be responsive. I’m aware that I then could us $(window).on(‘resize.... but I need to do it in pure css. Any css solution will do, can be as hackish as GeoHot, but i need to do it in css.

Comment: sorry I didn't get whats wrong with java-script. Most devices support it nowadays but I understand that that you want to make your website more accessible and inclusive. We have a good question here

Comment: CSS can't do that...yet.

Comment: not sure if there exists any trick/hack but there is no EASY way for it

Comment: @Andreas I realize that most devices/browsers/clients support JavaScript, but resizing stuff on window.resize will never feel as fast as doing it with css.

Comment: @sigsve you can try media queries. It's a css solution and the general strategy for responsive design.

Comment: @AbhishekPatel still it won't have same result as the percentage but I do agree that the intention is quite unconventional and that standard responsive design is not his intention

Comment: @AbhishekPatel if you think that will work, feel free to post a code example. Although I fail to see how media queries will in any way solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a unique hack, though it's only a half-answer (it might answer certain cases). Maybe someone with a few more wits can extend it and find a full solution. :-)

Based on the fact that <img> tags retain their proportion when scaling only one dimension, I put together a test that embeds a 1x1 spacer, and scales it to fit the height.

It does work well. Sadly, the downside is the image needs to be contained in an element which is a *sibling* to the content generating the height, and the width of the actual element with the content does not change.

Thus, if you're able to duplicate your content, it might actually work.

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/codesmith32/0xhqcry1/) to demonstrate it. And, here's the commented code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #outer {
        position:relative; /* limit the absolutely positioned #box */
    }
    #box {
        background-color:red;
        position:absolute;
        height:100%; /* make this box fill the height of #outer */
        display:block;
        z-index:-1; /* put it behind the content box generating height (maybe not if you want to hide / copy it) */
    }
    img {
        height:100%; /* generate the proportional square */
    }
    #inner {
        position:absolute;
        top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; /* make the inner box just fill the box generated by the image */
    }
    .centered {
        text-align:center;
        margin-top:50%;
        transform:translateY(-50%); /* quick vertical-centering css */
    }
    #box-text {
        color:white;
    }
    #height-box {
        display:inline-block; /* make the box width fit to the content - not vital either way */
    }
</style>
<div id="outer">
    <div id="box">
        <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7">
        <div id="inner">
            <p id="box-text" class="centered">Box</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="height-box" contenteditable="true">is<br>this<br>actually<br>possible?</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html):

```
<div class='box'> 
    <div class='content'>Aspect ratio of 1:1</div> 
</div>

.box{
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;     /* desired width */
}

.box:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;  /* initial ratio of 1:1*/
}

.content{
    position:  absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer, but it's the wrong way around. I want the element to be as wide as it is high, not as high as it is wide.